# how to install python-elementtree on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: centos, centos6, yum

How to install `python-elementtree` on CentOS 6.5 using `yum`? I need it for s3cmd, but their [documentation page](http://s3tools.org/repositories) doesn't explain it.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to add EPEL repo first, as [explained here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x):

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

Then, just run

```
sudo yum install s3cmd
```

Works for me.

Comment: You should probably take a moment to read the things you find on the internet and not just copy/paste them as you can get into a complete mess. You seem to have failed to notice that the commands you provide also install the remi repo which is not necessarily a problem but is indicative of your lack of attention.